# Authenticating to Google Auth with PHP cURL causes continuously forwarding

Tags: php, curl, oauth, token

I want to retrieve the Auth token from Google OAuth 2.0 ( i used [this](http://tutorialspage.com/simple-oauth2-example-using-php-curl/) tutorial) 
However, when I want to Authenticate, it results in an infinite loop of redirecting to nothing, thus kind of refreshing the page. Without any error messages. I cannot find out whats going wrong.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

// Admin Google API settings
// Portal url:

require_once('./curl.php');

define("CALLBACK_URL", "http://localhost/losapi/index2.php");  //Callback URL
define("AUTH_URL", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth");   //Used to get CODE (not Token!)
define("CLIENT_ID", "***");  // Personal
define("CLIENT_SECRET", "***");  // Personal
define("SCOPE", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.chromeos https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit"); // Depends on what you want to do.
define("APIURL_DIRECTORY","https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/");  // For Google Directory actions
define("CUSTOMER_ID","***");       // Personal
define("TOKEN_URL","https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token");   // URL to get Token (not code).
$curl = new \CURL\cURL();
// Initiate code for access token
if(isset($_GET["code"])){
  //DEBUG:  echo "Code: ".$_GET["code"];
  $url = TOKEN_URL."?";
  $url .= "code=".$_GET["code"];
  $url .= "&grant_type=authorization_code";
  $url .= "&client_id=". urlencode(CLIENT_ID);
  $url .= "&client_secret=". urlencode(CLIENT_SECRET);
  $url .= "&redirect_uri=". urlencode(CALLBACK_URL);

  $response = json_decode($curl->exeCurl($url,"POST"), true);
  if(isset($response)){
    if(array_key_exists("access_token", $response)) {
      $access_token = $response;
      setcookie("LOStoken", $response['access_token'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/");  // 86400 = 1 day
    }
  }
} else {

  if(isset($_POST['gettoken'])){

    $url = AUTH_URL."?";
    $url .= "response_type=code";
    $url .= "&client_id=". urlencode(CLIENT_ID);
    $url .= "&scope=". urlencode(SCOPE);
    $url .= "&redirect_uri=". urlencode(CALLBACK_URL);
    echo $curl->exeCurl($url,"GET");
  }
}

?>
```

curl.php

```
 namespace CURL;


class cURL
  {

// Algeneme cURL functie om web call te doen.
function exeCurl($url,$method,$body="") {
    $curl = curl_init();                      // initiate curl

    // Afhankelijk van TOKEN worden er andere headers gegeven.
    if(isset($_COOKIE["LOStoken"])){
        $headers = array(
            "Accept: */*",
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
            "Authorization: Bearer ". $_COOKIE["LOStoken"],
            "Connection: keep-alive",
            "Content-Length: ". strlen($body),
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "cache-control: no-cache"
        );
    } else {
        $headers = array(
            "Accept: */*",

            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Content-Length: ". strlen($body),
            "Connection: keep-alive",
            "cache-control: no-cache"
        );
    }

    // Set parameters for curl
    $params = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,                              // API URL
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,                   // Return answer
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,                  // SSL, enable in production
        //CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,                          // Max redirect
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,                   // If 301, follow redirect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,                            // Max timeout
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,    // HTTP version used
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,                 // HTTP method used
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers);                   // HTTP headers

    // Combineer curl + parameters
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $params);

    // Curl antwoorden
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);         // vul met errors
    curl_close($curl);                // Sluit verbinding

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;    // Als er errors zijn
    }
    if(array_key_exists("error", $response)) echo $response["error_description"];

    return $response;                 // Geef volledige antwoord terug
}


 }
```

Comment: You are trying to fetch the auth URL via cURL - that can not work, this authorization flow requires _user interaction_. You need to _redirect_ the user to this URL in their browser.

Comment: so instead of using Curl to get the code I need to use something else?

Comment: You can either redirect the user to that URL automatically; or you just put it into the `href` attribute of a link, so that the user can click on that then, to start the whole process. (I would recommend the second option in general, but at least during development. With an automatic redirect, there’s a good chance you’ll create a circular redirect again, if anything goes wrong.)

Comment: thanks . this did the trick

Comment: @04FS would you post that as an ans ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to fetch the auth URL via cURL - that can not work, this authorization flow requires user interaction. You need to redirect the user to this URL in their browser.

You can either redirect the user to that URL automatically; or you just put it into the `href` attribute of a link, so that the user can click on that then, to start the whole process. (I would recommend the second option in general, but at least during development. With an automatic redirect, there’s a good chance you’ll create a circular redirect again, if anything goes wrong.)